# Error with a property in a object | angular 7

Tags: angular, object, angular-cli, angular7

i have this issue, i am waiting for the arrival of an object that has the property "lugares", but visual studio code and angular cli tells me that this property does not exist, when in fact it exists and the application works correctly

[Visual Studio Code error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/436925593448087555/510138854871662623/unknown.png)

[Angular cli error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/436925593448087555/510139931906015272/unknown.png)

[Debugger chrome](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/436925593448087555/510138913038532618/unknown.png)

The code

```
public getLugares() {
    // return this.afDB.list("lugares");
    return this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT + "/.json").pipe(
      map(resultado => {
        debugger;
        const data = resultado.lugares;
        return data;
      })
    );
  }
```

How i can "resolve" this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the default type is `Object`, which doesn't have that property.

The quick fix is to do `this.http.get<any>(this.API_ENDPOINT + "/.json")`

**However**, this will not be type safe. You should create a class that represents that structure, and use that instead of `any`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for your answer, I'm learning angular and I did not know what could be done, what's that called <any>? Is it like telling him he can expect anything?

Comment: @darioxlz That's exactly right, it means it could be anything.

Comment: @darioxlz - Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (with the green check mark) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Typescript is complaining the property does not exists on that response. To fix it, Change it to any

```
map((resultado:any) => {
```

Comment: I keep checking the error, it worked for me to place the <any> in http.get, leaving http.get <any>